# Create GWT Datagrid with a checkbox column

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have successfully created a datagrid table with two columns. A checkbox col and a string col.  When I press a button I want to get the selected strings.  Currently when I press the button i get an empty hash set.

Selection Model:

```
private MultiSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<String>(KEY_PROVIDER);
```

Here is how I create the column

```
  Column<String, Boolean> checkColumn =
      new Column<String, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(String object) {
      // Get the value from the selection model.
      return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
    }
  };
```

Here is the method that is called from the button

```
public Set<String> getSelectedItems(){
Set<String> s = selectionModel.getSelectedSet();
return s;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two pieces are missing. You need to add a FieldUpdater to your checkColumn, and you need to link it to a checkbox manager. Replace T with your Object:

```
checkColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<T, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, T object, Boolean value) {
        getSelectionModel().setSelected(object, value);
        dataProvider.refresh();
    }
});
setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<T> createCheckboxManager(0));
```

Comment: What type is dataPrivider? / what am i refreshing?

Comment: It's a ListDataProvider<Object> or AsyncDataProvider<Object> that backs your DataGrid. At some point, you need to have dataProvider.addDataDisplay(myDataGrid);